# Sharing data between C++ and python, which implements keras\tensorflow

Tags: python, c++, ipc, interprocess

I am working on an application that uses C++ code and python code. 
Data is shared between the two scripts, C++ <---> python. Right now, I achieve this via SQLite, which very roughly takes care of concurrency , and it works correctly. The problem is that it's very slow for my purpose. 
My question is: how can I share data among python and C++ in a fast way? 
I read that Boost can be used to implement python code in C++, but since in my python code I work with keras/tensorflow, I don't think that solution works for me. 
I read that sockets are supposed to be slower than a local database, but I haven't tested this yet. Thanks!

Comment: If you want the same code in one application (share using memory) Cython is best. If not, use an API or shared database.

Comment: I cannot have the whole code in one application. The shared database is my current solution, but it's too slow. For the API you mean a connection with sockets?

Comment: One solution would be to create Python function wrappers for your C++ functions and then bind them together. [Here's a tutorial on Python C++ binding](https://www.hardikp.com/2017/12/30/python-cpp/).

Comment: @zmike do you know if it's possible to create such python wrappers for neural networks?

Comment: @maurocomi While I don't have experience with neural networks, I'm inclined to say yes. The function prototype may be declared in python but the actual implementation is in C++. Your python program would be calling the C++ functions as if they were Python functions.